# Inserting and removing recursively from a customized list

Tags: java, linked-list

The insert code seems to be working perfectly until the last insertion, where it doesn't add it in order instead it place it at the end of the list.

```
public void insert(Comparable item)
{
    if ( this.first == null || item.compareTo(this.first.data) <= 0)
    {
        addFirst(item); 
    }
    else if( item.compareTo(this.first.data) > 0 )
    {
        addLast(item);
    }
    else
    {
        Node oldFirst = this.first;
        this.first = this.first.next;

        insert(item);

        this.first = oldFirst;
    }
}
```

This is the output that it produces...

```
6 Item(s) 

5
16
21
22
45
23
```

---

The remove method stops compiling after it removes the item and I can't figure out why.

```
public Comparable remove(Comparable item)
{
    if( this.first == null )
    {
        return null;
    }

    Node oldFirst = this.first;

    if( this.first.next == null && this.first.data.equals(item) )
    {
        Comparable found = this.first.data;
        this.first = null;
        return found;
    }                

    this.first = this.first.next;

    if( this.first.data.equals(item) )
    {
        Comparable found = this.first.data;
        oldFirst.next = this.first.next;
        this.first = oldFirst;
        return found;
    }

    Comparable foundIt = remove(item);       

    return foundIt;
}
```

this is the output from the remove method....

```
at List.remove(List.java:164)
Removed: 21. List has: 4 Item(s) 
at List.remove(List.java:164)

16
at List.remove(List.java:164)
22
45
at TestRecursion.main(TestRecursion.java:87)
```

Comment: What is stacktrace for the crash?

Comment: Can you put complete code.Will let you know the issue then?

Comment: Would it be possible to see your entire class?

Comment: Also, when you say `The remove method crashes after it removes the item`, do you mean that it behaves incorrectly as you show, or that it throws an exception?

Answer (score 0):

I notice you call addLast if item is greater than your first element. This won't give you a sorted list.

Consider calling insert with 1, 4, 2, 3.  Output would be in exactly that order. 1, 4, 2 3.

Also as to why remove is crashing...

```
//what if its last item, and the data !.equals(item)?
if( this.first.next == null && this.first.data.equals(item) )
{
    Comparable found = this.first.data;
    this.first = null;
    return found;
}   
this.first = this.first.next;
//first could be null here if you are at end of list.
if( this.first.data.equals(item) )
{
    Comparable found = this.first.data;
    oldFirst.next = this.first.next;
    this.first = oldFirst;
    return found;
}
```

I suggest you use your debugger. Should clear things up quickly.

Comment: For the insert I tried to fix this by creating a new node with the item data then pointing the new node.next to point to first.next and first.next to the new node, but that doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your insert method adds 23 last because

```
 item.compareTo(this.first.data) > 0
```

23 is indeed more that your **first element**.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void insert(Comparable item)
{
    first = insertRecursively(first, item);
}
private static Node insert(Node node, Comparable item)
    if ( node == null || item.compareTo(node.data) <= 0)
    {
        Node created = new Node(item);
        created.next = node;
        return created;            
    }
    else
    {
        node.next = insertRecursively(node.next, item);
        return node;
    }
}
```

Doing it recursively one needs to alter the just checked first/next.